# log4j error : Could not read configuration file from URL (when launching HermesJMS)

Tags: java, log4j, hermes-jms

I'm trying to install HermesJMS.
Setup works correctly, but when I want to launch it, I have this error

> log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file from URL
> [file:/c/DevTools/tools/HermesJMS/bin/log4j.props].

The problem is that log4j.props exists in this directory as well as directories.

Here is the full log:

```
        log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file from URL [file:/c/DevTools/tools/HermesJMS/bin/log4j.props].
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: \c\DevTools\tools\HermesJMS\bin\log4j.props (Le chemin d▒acc▒s sp▒cifi▒ est introuvable (means that this directory can't be found))
                at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
                at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
                at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
                at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
                at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
                at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
                at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1067)
                at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:459)
                at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:471)
                at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:125)
                at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:118)
                at hermes.browser.HermesBrowser.<clinit>(HermesBrowser.java:151)
        log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [file:/c/DevTools/tools/HermesJMS/bin/log4j.props].
        log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (hermes.impl.ConfigDAOImpl).
        log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
        f▒vr. 06, 2024 1:39:51 PM com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.util.XmlFactory createParserFactory
        GRAVE: null
        org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing
                at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.setFeature(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.setFeatures(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParserImpl(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.setFeature(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.util.XmlFactory.createParserFactory(XmlFactory.java:121)
                at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.getXMLReader(UnmarshallerImpl.java:139)
                at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:276)
                at hermes.JAXBHermesLoader.load(JAXBHermesLoader.java:302)
                at hermes.HermesContext.load(HermesContext.java:57)
                at hermes.HermesInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(HermesInitialContextFactory.java:95)
                at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
                at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
                at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
                at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
                at hermes.browser.HermesBrowser.loadConfig(HermesBrowser.java:1031)
                at hermes.browser.HermesBrowser$3.run(HermesBrowser.java:232)
                at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
                at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
                at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
                at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
                at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
                at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Do you have any clue about what could cause this issue? Thank you.
I looked over stackoverflow but this error is mainly related to Java code. But I know this jar works elsewhere, so I assume the problem is elsewhere

Searching over stackoverflow, tried parameters for log4j when executing the script

Comment: You don't have a `\c\DevTools\tools\HermesJMS\bin\log4j.props` file, you have a `C:\DevTools\tools\HermesJMS\bin\log4j.props` file: remark the missing colon.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, but since I do not have access to the code, is there a workaround? Thanks

Comment: The string `file:/c/DevTools/tools/HermesJMS/bin/log4j.props` is almost certainly in a configuration file or Java system property (`log4j.configuration`).

Comment: I haven't any log4j.configuration file on my system, but I managed to get it working using SoapUI. Thank you!